# Divergence, contraction and lie derivatives

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, lie-derivative

[image]

I'm working through this question. I can show the forward direction in (a) but can't show the converse. I have $\delta/\delta t \phi^*_t \mu$ evaluated at t=0 is 0, but I can't see how I conclude from here?

In (b), proving the hint is fine. I have also that $d(i_X\mu)= \mu$. Is this true? I'm not really sure what the RHS actually means, and I have no idea how to get the desired result. Can you point me in the right direction?

NB. This is homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that ${d\over dt} \Phi _t^* \mu= \Phi_t^* L_X\mu$. In this case it is $0$, therefore $\Phi _t^* \mu$ is constant equal to $\mu$.

For b, the Einstein convention is used $\partial X^i\over \partial x^i$ means that you have to sum over all indexes. $L_X\mu= d(\sum _i X^i (-1)^i dx^1...dx^{i-1} dx^{i+1} d x^n)= \sum _i {\partial X^i\over \partial x^i}$

Comment: It is enough to check this formula at $t=0$. Then this can be proved by simple calculation when $X$ is the constant vector field, say $\partial \over \partial x_1$, with flow $\Phi _t(x_1,,...x_n) =(x_1+t,x_2, , ...x_n)$. We know that on the open $\Omega$ where  $X\not = 0$ every point admits a neighborhood and a chart where $X$ is constant. To complete the proof, note that in the interior complementary of $\Omega$, the formula is obvious as $X=0$ and $\Phi_t= Id$. So the formula is true on en dense subset, and everywhere by continuity.